# Adjusting the time zone when using momentJs with React

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I am fetching a datetime value from the back end and I use the following line of code to get the time apart from the date :

```
 {moment(element.dateTime).format('h:mm:ss a')}
```

I just want to know how to adjust the time zone in the code above to be the same as my country's time zone. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Moment by default will parse the date to your local computer. https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the utcOffset method as below, it takes the GMT Offset value. Change '+05:30' to whatever value you want

{moment.utc(element.dateTime).utcOffset("+05:30").format('h:mm:ss a')}

Also, Moment by default parses the date to your local timezone.

You can also use moment-timezone for timezone purposes, it asks for timezone name instead of gmtOffset. If you wish to use format method of moment though, there are certain limitations to it.
[Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)